# Meaning of -1 port value in java.net.URL?

Tags: java

I need to create an URL based on the port number by using java.net.url class's constructor. To do that I've used the constructor below,

`public URL(String protocol, String host, int port, String file){}`
I need to create two different URL; if the port is 80, need to ignore the port, else URL should contain the port number. I'm not able to send port number as null, there is a value which is -1. When I use -1 for port, it creates the URL without port.

My problem is documentation of constructor; above of the constructor there is a description and that decription is
*"Specifying a {@code port} number of {@code -1} indicates that the URL should use the default port for the protocol."*. As I mentioned, I don't want to use default port number. If that is the case, how can I create a URL only with a such constructor?

BTW, I know, I could use only String version, I don't want to write two *new URL* to do that. Basically, I want to write something like this,
`new URL(scheme, serverName, serverPort == 80 ? -1 : serverPort, contextPath); // as I mentioned based on the documentation of URL constructor, -1 gets the default port number, but in the code it is not like that.`

Waiting for your suggestions. Thank you.

**EDIT**
`new URL(scheme, serverName, serverPort == 80 ? null: serverPort, contextPath);`

Comment: "As I mentioned, I don't want to use default port number" - it sounds like you do. I read that as saying "Create the URL without a port number, so that whatever interprets the URL will use the default port."

Comment: As @JonSkeet said you are actually using the default port for the current protocol (supposing that you are going with http, then it's 80). 
If you want a random port at runtime the you can do something like
new InetSocketAddress(0).getPort()
that will give you a free port

Comment: "Basically, I want to write something like this" So why don't you do exactly that? Does it give you a result you don't expect? Can you edit the question to add the result that you get and the result that you expect

Comment: as @Raffaele mentioned default port for http is 80. So, if port is 80 then, url shouldn't be like stackoverflow.com:80. It should be like stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @Joni yes, but based on the documentation uses default port which is 80 for http. That's why I'm confused, my implementation's behavior as I expected, but the documentation is not like the code.

Comment: @JonSkeet can you check my edit?

Comment: I really think you're just misunderstanding the documentation.

Comment: `port` is an `int` field in the `URL` implementation that I looked at. That means it *can not* be `null`. `-1` is the equivalent of "not specified" (which is **also** interpreted as "use the default port and "don't print a port number in the external form"). There is no *third* state.

Comment: @JoachimSauer so, you're saying, if port -1, then created url will not contain the port?

Comment: @ytWho: exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the documentation is what's confusing you. When the documentation says

> Specifying a {@code port} number of {@code -1} indicates that the URL should use the default port for the protocol.

What it means is that the URL is created *without a port number*. But when you connect to a host, you need to use a port, and if the URL does not have a port, the *default port for the protocol* will be used.

- The string representation of the URL **will not** use the default port.
- The network connection created by URL.openConnectiom **will** use the default port.

Answer (score 1):

The URL class itself simply stores the port number if you provide it or doesn't store it if you don't.

If it doesn't store one (internally and in parameters that's represented as `-1`), then the external form of the URL will simply not have a visible port specified. That seems to be exactly what you want to do.

When it says "If the port is not specified, the default port for the protocol is used instead." it simply means that if you actually **access** the URL in some way (in other words when the code **must** know a specific port) and you didn't specify one then the handler will just use whatever the default is in the protocol.

In other words: `http://example.org/` and `http://example.org:80/` are two different URLs (the first would have `port` set to -1 in an `URL` object). But if you try to connect to them, then they would do the exact same steps (because in the absence of an explicit port specification any HTTP client will use port `80`).

Answer (score 0):

So you want the constructor:

```
public URL(String protocol, String host, int port, String file){}
```

not to heed the port, when it's 80?

Shouldn't something like

```
if(port == 80) return URL(protocol, host, file)
else return URL(protocol, host, port, file)
```

be sufficient?

Since `int` is primitive, you cannot `null` it. Therefore you **must** define a number here, regardless if you like it or not.

The [three argument constructor](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/net/URL.java#L386) is just setting the port to -1 as well:

```
public URL(String protocol, String host, String file)
        throws MalformedURLException {
    this(protocol, host, -1, file);
}
```

Therefore your best bet is to do the following:

```
URL url = new URL("http","localhost",port == 80 ? -1 : port,null);
```

Since all of these constructors are leading to the five argument constructor, the port will be evaluated as follows:

```
        if (port < -1) {
            throw new MalformedURLException("Invalid port number :" +
                                                port);
        }
        this.port = port;
        authority = (port == -1) ? host : host + ":" + port;
```

You have no choice here.